# Upload crt to ec2 running Amazon Linux

Tags: linux, ssl

I have an ec2 running Amazon Linux. I have a crt and need to upload it to /etc/pki/tls/certs.

SFTP says permission denied, and I can't change the permissions.

I have an SSH connection, but I don't know how to upload a file via the terminal.

I looks at recommendations involving scp and tried...

```
scp custom.crt ec2-user@ip-172-31-1-182:/etc/pki/tls/certs
```

I got...

```
The authenticity of host 'ip-172-31-1-182 (172.31.1.182)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is xxxxxxxxx
ECDSA key fingerprint is xxxxxxxxx
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'ip-172-31-1-182,172.31.1.182' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
lost connection
```

Is there something wrong in my scp command?

Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 0):

by default ec2-user doesn't have permission to write any file in `/etc/pki/tls/certs` location. you can simply scp the cert to home of ec2-user or in `/tmp` directory. after that ssh to the server and use `sudo` to copy/move the file in `/etc/pki/tls/certs` location. 
Below is command for the same:

```
scp custom.crt ec2-user@ip-172-31-1-182:/home/ec2-user
ssh ec2-user@ip-172-31-1-182
sudo mv custom.crt /etc/pki/tls/certs
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When I enter the first command, I get..."ssh: Could not resolve hostname ip-172-31-1-182: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
lost connection" I'm issuing the command when I'm in my local directory that contains custom.crt. But I am not in an SSH session. Is that correct?

Comment: I just tried the scp command in an SSH session and got "Permission denied (publickey).lost connection"

Comment: **ip-172-31-1-182** is private IP(accessible within network only). use public IP to connect or use VPN Connection